# HTTP 404 while using tornado's StaticFileHandler class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, static-files

I'm getting the following traceback while using tornado's `StaticFileHandler` class.
Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1334, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 628, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 109, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 175, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2110, in get
    self.root, absolute_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2286, in validate_absolute_path
    raise HTTPError(404)
HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

This is the structure of my directory :

Server/

- httpserver.py
- static/static/foo/bar/files.extension

The content of httpserver.py :

```
settings = {
'debug': True,
'autoreload': True,
}

application = tornado.web.Application([\
            (r"/(.*)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,\
            {"path":"static/static/foo/bar/"}),],\
            **settings)
application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I've gone through the similar questions, they don't seem to give me a proper solution.

Comment: because when you import `httpserver` it is colliding with your file `httpserver.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem fixed by myself. I added a keyword argument static_path, a path from root to the directory from where the .py file is. The corrected, working code :

```
settings = {
'debug': True,
'autoreload': True,
'static_path': '/home/path/to/pythonFile'
}

application = tornado.web.Application([\

            (r"(.*)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,\
            {"path":"static/foo/bar"}),],\
            **settings)
application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: What .py file? I'm having this exact traceback.

Comment: httpserver.py file